# RavenDB Changes API never fires

Tags: ravendb

I can't seem to get the Changes API event to fire.

I subscribe and I have tried changing a document via the Studio as well as making a change in code via the client, but the change API never fires.

Environment:

- RavenDB 5.0.3
- .Net Core 3.1
- Using client certificates for auth

Ideas?

Here's my simple code:

```
private void SubscribeToDbChanges()
{
    Store
    .Changes()
    .ForDocumentsInCollection<ReferenceDataProvider>()
    .Subscribe(change =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data subscription changed");
        Reinitialize();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
        var subscription = Store.Changes();
        await subscription.EnsureConnectedNow();
        var observableWithTask = subscription
            .ForDocumentsInCollection<ReferenceDataProvider>();
        observableWithTask.Subscribe(change =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data subscription changed");
            Reinitialize();
        });
        await observableWithTask.EnsureSubscribedNow();
```

Comment: That works, thank you. It looks quite different than the documentation though. Weird.
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/Csharp/client-api/changes/how-to-subscribe-to-document-changes

Comment: @mpalmer78 wow that's very weird. I couldn't find anything about this across the internet except for this SO article. Thanks for this question!